# I want to learn how to develop Iphone apps and android apps at the same time, any suggestions?

Tags: iphone, android

I want to get into mobile apps, I was wondering if there are any known resources (books, tutorials, etc) that teach both iphone and android development at the same time (I realize this might not be a good idea, if you have an opinion why this is a bad idea I'm interested in that too)?

Are there tools that abstract the environment out. For example, write the program in language X, push a button and you have both an iphone and android app? If these do exist, any opinions on them?

Answer (score 6):

To be honest, I'd be very surprised if you found such a book as whilst there are commonalities in the approach (both are event driven, etc.) the specifics of the underlying languages of Objective-C and Java are quite different, hence it would be a somewhat splintered tome.

I'd also be tempted to avoid any tools that "abstract the environment out", as you'll just end up producing apps that don't *quite* feel right, at least in my experience, as they inevitably won't be using all of the available native functionality provided by the environment. Then again, perhaps that's sufficient for your requirements.

Irrespective, in terms of good books for iOS (I've not yet delved into Android), I'd heartily recommend [iPhone Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide](http://www.bignerdranch.com/book/iphone_programming_the_big_nerd_ranch_guide), perhaps after a read of [Learn Objective-C on the Mac](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430218150).

If however, you just want to dip your toes, there's a nice starter for ten on the Apple developer site - [Learning Objective-C: A Primer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007594), which in conjunction with Apple's [iOS Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072) should provide a good overview. (Incidentally, the Apple [online class reference documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/) is excellent and perhaps worth a browse in and of itself.)

No doubt other posters will be able to recommend good resources for the Android side of things.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on what your requirements are. Web apps can do a large portion of what native apps can do these days. If you really want a tool that "abstract[s] the environment out", you can have it: it's called HTML5.

There are also some tools like [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) that generally provide some version of web apps or hybrid apps (basically, a web app running in a customized browser that provides some additional native-app functionality). There are also a number of proprietary solutions, most of which want your app to be hosted on their servers, charge a per-user fee, etc. This is probably not what you mean when you say you want to learn iPhone and Android programming, but they might be a good solution if you just want to produce a mobile tool for use within your enterprise.

If you really want to learn to build native iPhone and Android apps, I'd think you'd want to avoid third-party cross platform tools. Pick one platform and learn to use it. It'll be a lot of work, depending on how much object-oriented programming experience you have, but it's also a lot of fun. Once you've got a solid handle on one platform, take some time to learn the other. There are a lot of big differences between the two platforms, but there are also some similarities. Trying to learn both at the same time, I think, will probably take longer than learning one and then the other.